# Apache: убрать кеширование

Tags: apache, кэширование

Поднимаю dev сервер на `localhost`'е для `Django` сайта. Поставил `apache+mod_wsgi`. Но после каждого изменения надо делать

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Что бы применить изменения. Как я понял `apache` кеширует все это дело. Как избавиться от этого?

Comment: Еще актуально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode
http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2008/12/using-modwsgi-when-developing-django.html
http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/02/source-code-reloading-with-modwsgi-on.html